# How to make parenthetical citations in small font using a lua-filter via pandoc?

Tags: lua, markdown, pandoc, citations

I would like to write all parenthetical citations in small fonts when I produce HTML/revealjs outputs from markdown using pandoc. Putting `<small>...</small>` tags around the `[@citation]` notation (e.g. `<small>[@citation]</small>`) can be the way to achieve that effect, but I just leave `[@citation]`s as they are since there are a lot of `[@citation]` in my multiple `.md` files.

I came up with the following lua-filter (say `small-parencite.lua`) that selectively makes the font size of parenthetical citations small. However, this lua-filter does not change the font size of any parenthetical citation.

```lua
Cite = function(cite)
    content = cite.content
    -- if FORMAT:match 'html' or FORMAT:match 'revealjs' then
        if cite.citations == 'NormalCitation' then
            pandoc.Str('<small>' .. content .. '</small>')
        end
    -- end
    return cite
end
```

Does anybody point out what I am missing in that lua-filter? Note that I want the font size of narrative citations to remain the same as normal texts as shown below:

[image]

## MWE

### `small-parencite.lua`

```lua
Cite = function(cite)
    content = cite.content
    -- if FORMAT:match 'html' or FORMAT:match 'revealjs' then
        if cite.citations == 'NormalCitation' then
            pandoc.Str('<small>' .. content .. '</small>')
        end
    -- end
    return cite
end
```

### `test.md`

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    md_extensions: -ascii_identifiers
    pandoc_args:
      - small-parencite.lua
references:
- author:
  - family: Allaire
    given: JJ
  - family: Xie
    given: Yihui
  - family: McPherson
    given: Jonathan
  - family: Luraschi
    given: Javier
  - family: Ushey
    given: Kevin
  - family: Atkins
    given: Aron
  - family: Wickham
    given: Hadley
  - family: Cheng
    given: Joe
  - family: Chang
    given: Winston
  - family: Iannone
    given: Richard
  id: R-rmarkdown
  issued: 2020
  note: R package version 2.3
  title: "rmarkdown: Dynamic Documents for R"
  title-short: rmarkdown
  type: book
  url: "https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown"
- author:
  - family: Xie
    given: Yihui
  edition: 2nd
  id: knitr2015
  issued: 2015
  note: ISBN 978-1498716963
  publisher: Chapman; Hall/CRC
  publisher-place: Boca Raton, Florida
  title: Dynamic Documents with R and knitr
  type: book
  url: "https://yihui.org/knitr/"
---

I want to write all parenthetical citations in small fonts like this:

This is knitr <small>[@knitr2015]</small>.

But I do not want to use `<small>...</small>` tags (e.g. `<small>[@citation]</small>`) to achieve that effect. I just leave `[@citation]`s as they are like this:

This is knitr [@knitr2015]

Note that I want the font size of narrative citations to remain the same as normal texts as shown below:

This is a markdown variant by @R-rmarkdown.

# References
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```lua
function Cite(el)
  if el.citations[1].mode == 'NormalCitation' then
    return {
      pandoc.RawInline("html", "<small>"),
      el,
      pandoc.RawInline("html", "</small>")
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your original code is so close! I modified your code so that I am able to present only parenthetical citations (not any narrative citations) in small fonts. I appreciate your brilliant suggestion!